# conditional probability (logic question)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logic, conditional-probability

I would appreciate help with the following question. I have myself proposed the question and so it possible that the question is ill posed.

A zoo receives $500,000$ visitors. Overall, $3\%$ of these visitors went to see the elephants. Half of the visitors are from Australian and $4\%$ of Australian visitors saw the elephants. $60\%$ of the visitors are male and $3.5\%$ of male visitors saw the elephants. what would be the probability of a visitor seeing the elephants if they were from Australia AND male?

we know $p(e), p(e|m), p(e|a), p(m)$ and $p(a)$ where e indicates seeing the elephants, m indicates male and a indicates represent Australian. How can we get $p(e|m,a)$?

Comment: Seems to me there is not enough information to do that. Given what you are providing, you cannot answer an even simpler question -- what is the probability that a given visitor is a male Australian.

Comment: Is it given that the visitor is from Australia and is male or you have to find its probability also

Answer (score 3):

I think this question cannot be answered with the information provided. 
As someone commented, the association between being male and being Australian is missing, which you would need to calculate the number of Australian male visitors. Similarly I think you need this information for the number of these visitors who saw the elephants.

Essentially, most Australian visitors at the elephants could be female or most of them could be male, which would clearly change the probability you ask about.